# Can I use this proof that $\lim_{x\to p}[1/f(x)] = 1/\lim_{x\to p}f(x)$?

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification

My textbook on Calculus use a much wordy proof. Maybe the author didn't want to declare that $f(x)/f(x) = 1$ since we have not prooven it. And maybe there is more in this statement that meets the eye. Maybe in real analysis $f(x)/f(x)$ is not always $1$.

**The proof**:

Since $f(x)/f(x) = 1$ we derive this (we use the rule for the limit of a multiplication):

$1 = \lim_{x\to p}[f(x)/f(x)] = \lim_{x\to p}[f(x)*1/f(x)] = \lim_{x\to p}f(x)*\lim_{x\to p}[1/f(x)]$

$\lim_{x\to p}[1/f(x)] = 1/\lim_{x\to p}f(x)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not completely. Note that the rule for the limit of multiplication usually is formulated somewhat like this:

> If $\lim_{x\to p}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to p} g(x)$ exist, then $\lim_{x\to p}f(x)g(x)$ exists and equals $\lim_{x\to p}f(x)\cdot \lim_{x\to p}g(x)$.

For your proof to work you need therfore a few preliminaries: To show that $\lim_{x\to p}\frac1{f(x)}$ exists in the first place. And in fact to allow the use of $\frac{f(x)}{f(x)}=1$ you need that $f(x)$ is not zero too often (though this will readily follow from a precondition of the theorem you want to proof that you forgot to mention!).